# Run script when clicked on picture in published Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I used the script underneath in Google Spreadsheet and added an image that when clicked upon runs the GOTOSHEETONE function to navigate to sheet: SHEETONE.

So far so good. However, when I publish my document this function is not executed anymore. A link to a Google form, which is also in my document, does work when published. Is there a way to make this function also run in published document mode?

```
function showSheetByName(Name) {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(Name);
   SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}

function GOTOSHEETONE() {
   showSheetByName("SHEETONE");
}
```

Comment: Working with images is tricky. The image needs to be publicly available and (I believe) outside your domain. Why not create an UI with a button (and add image to button)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make this function also run in published document
>   mode?

The short answer is, unfortunately, no. The published version of a spreadsheet has many functional limitations, and this is one of them.